# Explain an C expression with ? : and >

Tags: c, operators, argc

Could anyone kindly explain me the use of a following expression in C?

```
double irate = argc > 1? atof(arg[1]) : 1;
double orate = argc > 2? atof(arg[2]) : 2;
```

(Taken from the beginning of an soxr example https://sourceforge.net/p/soxr/code/ci/master/tree/examples/1-single-block.c.)

Does it mean something like:

*"if number of arguments is bigger than one, take the first argument and place it into the `irate` variable, otherwise put number 1 into the same variable"*?

Similarly with the second possible argument...

> `atof()` is just a libc conversion of a string (arguments are always treated as strings in Unix/Linux) to `double`, error (while conversion) handling is not provided.

Am I right?

Comment: No, it means the second and third elements (if given). In C arrays are indexed from `[0]`. If those are from `int main(int argc, char *arg[])` then the first element is the name of the executable, and the following elements would be the first, second argument *of the command line*.

Comment: But argv[0]: is the name of the programme run, so that it's not a real parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double irate = argc > 1? atof(arg[1]) : 1;
```

Can be written as:

```
if (argc > 1)
    irate = atof(arg[1]);
else
    irate = 1
```

Or can be read as: if the argument count is greater than one, convert the second argument from an ascii string to a float and store it in the variable irate, otherwise set it to the value of 1.

Same for the second line.

Have a look at [Conditional operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator)

Answer (score 0):

`irate` and `orate` are supposed to be provided from command line, respectively as the first argument after the executable name (`argv [1]`) and as the second argument  (`argv [2]`).

The expression

```
 double irate = argc > 1? atof(arg[1]) : 1;
```

is don to initialize the proper variable, but only if the corresponding argument has been provided. If not, the conversion would be meaningless,  so a **default value** (`1`) is assigned.

The same can be said for `orate`: the default value `2` is assigned if the corresponding argument is not provided.